# Java applet HttpClient AccessControlException

Tags: java, applet, privileges, apache-httpclient-4.x, accesscontrolexception

I have created an applet which uses the HttpClient from Apache HTTP Components. The applet is supposed to open a remote webpage and print the source of the page to console. The code works fine when ran from IDE (NetBeans), however when deployed in a webpage it throws an AccessControlException:

```
access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "www.hardwarebase.net" "resolve")
```

Upon reading similar questions concerning the problem, it seemed like the problem was in the applet not being signed. I self-signed it, so when I ran it the next time, the applet asked for and got the permissions.

Still, I get the same exception. Here is the code of the main applet class:

```
public class MyApplet extends java.applet.Applet {
    public DefaultHttpClient client;
        public String useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1";
    public void init() 
    {                   
        resize(150,25);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();       
        String page = Get("http://www.hardwarebase.net"));
        System.out.println(page);   

    }

    public String Get(String url)
    {
        final HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setHeader("User-Agent", useragent);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = (HttpResponse)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                    public Object run() {
                            try {
                                return client.execute(request);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MyApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }

                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                );
                return _getResponseBody(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return "";
    }

    public String Post(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
    {
        final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setHeader("User-Agent", useragent);
        try {
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response;

                    try {
                        response = (HttpResponse)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                                public Object run() {
                                        try {
                                            return client.execute(request);
                                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                                            Logger.getLogger(MyApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                        }

                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        return _getResponseBody(response.getEntity());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }

    public String _getResponseBody(final HttpEntity entity) throws IOException, ParseException 
    {
        if (entity == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null"); }
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        if (instream == null) { return ""; }
        if (entity.getContentLength() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity too large to be buffered in memory"); }
        String charset = getContentCharSet(entity);
        if (charset == null) { charset = HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET; }
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, charset);
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        try 
        {
            char[] tmp = new char[1024];
            int l;
            while ((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) 
            {
                buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
            }   
        } 
        finally 
        {
            reader.close();
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    }

    public String getContentCharSet(final HttpEntity entity) throws ParseException 
    {
        if (entity == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null"); }
        String charset = null;
        if (entity.getContentType() != null) 
        {
            HeaderElement values[] = entity.getContentType().getElements();

            if (values.length > 0) 
            {   
                NameValuePair param = values[0].getParameterByName("charset");

                if (param != null) { charset = param.getValue(); }  
            }
        }

        return charset;
    }

}
```

How can I resolve this AccessControlException?

Comment: It's still possible that the client's security policy is rejecting the attempt to connect via a socket. Applets user designed to be VERY security conscious, even to the point of annoyance. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html for some more details. If you can, you might want to consider Java's Web Start instead

Comment: Well I know for a fact that there are applets that connect to remote hosts with no problems, the only button user needs to press is the "Allow" one when the page is loaded. An example is the VidFetch applet which many websites use to stream videos from other hosts without taking up their website's bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by switching from HttpClient to URLConnection. I am not sure why doesn't URLConnection throw the exception, while HttpClient does.